# tf.grad() returns matrix of zeros

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I trained a CNN on an MNIST dataset, and planned to use it for inference with tf.js.

However, when checking the model's gradients with respect to one of the test images, I notice
I keep getting a zero matrix. If this is an important observation, the
zero matrix has the correct shape for the input image.

```
function getGradient(img, yTrue) {

    yTrue = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d([yTrue], 'int32'), 10);

    function f(x) {
        return tf.metrics.categoricalCrossentropy(yTrue, model.predict(x));    
    }
    var g = tf.grad(f);

    var grad = g(img);
    return grad;
}
```

The Python equivalent allowed me to succesfully compute the gradient.

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

//already used one-hot encoding to convert the input_label
def getGradient(input_image, input_label):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(input_image)
    prediction = model(input_image)
    loss = loss_object(input_label, prediction)

  gradient = tape.gradient(loss, input_image)

  return gradient
```